# Why is Windows 11 accessing $BitMap, $Mft and $LogFile file on hard drive during idle?

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, windows-11

I have a spinning hard drive which I use only for backup. The hard drive is noisy (as most spinning disks are), but normally it turns itself off during inactivity and produces no sound, which is what I want.

However, during idle time (when I don't touch computer for 15 min) it becomes very noisy. I opened Resource Monitor too see which apps are using it, and it shows that "System" process is accessing the following three files:

- $BitMap (NTFS Free Space Map)
- $Mft (NTFS File Table)
- $LogFile (NTFS Volume log)

Question: why is System accessing the disk? Can I turn it off?

Comment: Is it trying to defragmenting the disk/seeing if the drive needs defragmenting? Chkdisking? SSDs are pretty awesome.

Comment: @Gantendo I'm not sure. It says "System" for the process, so I can not tell. Yes I'm using SSD for everything, this is just a backup 16 TB drive.

Comment: Had the same question myself. Loud HDD, annoying me it's running without need be. What Gantendo said is 100% correct, I went to Properties -> Tools -> Optimize on the drive in question and after considerable time de-fragmenting. It seems to of stopped clunking around when idle.